# Multiple uses of a component lead to React is not defined error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am rendering a Card component in my App. When I only have one card, everything is fine, as soon as I have more than one I get a `ReferenceError: React is not defined`

```
<div className="App">
  <Card />
  <Card />
</div>
```

My card component code is as follows (the styling is done using Emotion):

```
/** @jsx jsx */

import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { css, jsx } from "@emotion/core";

import useComponentSize from "@rehooks/component-size";

function Card(props: any) {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  let size = useComponentSize(ref);
  let { width } = size;

  const style = css({
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: width > 600 ? "row" : "column",
    "& div": {
      marginTop: 10,
      flex: 1
    },
    "& img": {
      objectFit: "cover",
      flex: 1
    },
    "& h2": {
      paddingLeft: 10,
      paddingRight: 10
    },
    "& p": {
      paddingLeft: 10,
      paddingRight: 10
    }
  });

  return (
    <div css={style} ref={ref}>
      <img src="ribena.webp" alt="" />
      <div>
        <h2>placeholder</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem
          molestiae, vitae esse et dignissimos consequuntur provident eligendi
          labore beatae laboriosam.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

I have NPM installed all the required dependencies and imported React into both the card component and the app component. I don't see why it is defined when there is one card but not when there are two.

I am using Typescript in the project, if that makes a difference, with Typescript strict mode set to false.

The only non-stable release I am using is `@ionic/react`. Maybe that is causing the problem? Or maybe it is Typescript, as Typescript often causes weird problems in my (limited) experience

I have recreated on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/k3km526z6v) The error is intermittent and I have seen the same error recreated in this sandbox... sometimes it errors sometimes it doesn't ‍♂️

[image]

I am using the [rehooks/component-size package](https://github.com/rehooks/component-size)

Comment: Could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)?

Comment: Check your html. This may be caused by mixing `.js` from different builds.

Comment: In your tsconfig.json, do you have `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` enabled? If not, you may need to import React using the follow construct: `import * as React from "react"`

Comment: I have `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` in my tsconfig.json. Do I need to use `import * as React from "react"` every time I need to import React?

Comment: Just opened the SandBox and all 6 cards loaded just fine. What happened?

Comment: It's temperamental. Sometimes it works. Sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: I've had the same problem until I replaced emotion with styled-components. You should probably follow this issue: https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/1303